# R function to get only columns with datetime

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to get only the columns with datetime format. Using `select_if` for numeric is working but I can't find a function for datetime:

result set with only numeric columns

```
orders %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% View()
```

result set with only dttm columns ?

```
orders %>% select_if(is.datetime) %>% View()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is.POSIXt` or `is.POSIXct` from `lubridate` to select date-time columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

orders %>% select_if(is.POSIXct)
```

If you are on `dplyr` 1.0.0 or above.

```
orders %>% select(where(is.POSIXct))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) inherits(x, "POSIXct"), orders)
```